# Adding multiple PivotFields in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a macro which makes a PivotTable. Currently I've been able to find some code that helped me create it, the problem is that I can't find a way to add various PivotFields using a for look or array, currently I use this code to add PivotFields:

```
'set data field - specifically change orientation to a data field and
'set its function property:
 With PvtTbl.PivotFields("S1")

.Orientation = xlDataField

.Function = xlSum

.NumberFormat = "#,##0"

.Position = 1

End With

With PvtTbl.PivotFields("S2")

.Orientation = xlDataField

.Function = xlSum

.NumberFormat = "#,##0"

.Position = 2

End With
```

As you can see i just repeat the same code to add another field, is there a better way for adding multiple fields instead of just copy paste the same code? I need to add 22 fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all your pivot fields are named "Sxx" where xx is a number, give this a shot:

```
'set data field - specifically change orientation to a data field 
'and set its function property:

Dim I as Integer

For I = 1 to 22
  With PvtTbl.PivotFields("S" & i)
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Function = xlSum
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    .Position = i
  End With
Next
```

Comment: Yes they centrally are name as "Sxx", and yes it works just fine, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

`PivotFields` acts strangely because it's actually the union of several collections, one for each possible field Orientation.

From the documentation:

> In some cases, it may be easier to use one of the properties that
>   returns a subset of the PivotTable fields. The following accessor
>   methods are available:
>
> ColumnFields property
>
> DataFields property
>
> HiddenFields property
>
> PageFields property
>
> RowFields property
>
> VisibleFields property

If you want to set the orientations to a loop, you probably want to loop over the HiddenFields collection because you don't want to be adjusting the fields that are already set to the row or column orientation.

The problem is, once you set the orientation of an element in HiddenFields, it's no longer hidden, so it gets removed from the collection. That means a normal for loop won't work, unless you made the for loop go backwards. I think it's clearer if you use a Do loop like this.

```
Dim pf As PivotField
Do Until PvtTable.HiddenFields.Count = 0
    Set pf = PvtTbl.HiddenFields(1)
    pf.Orientation = xlDataField
    pf.Function = xlSum
    pf.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
Loop
```

If you're in a situation where you have a list of fields that you want to set to data orientation, but don't have a naming convention, you could do something like this.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim data_fields As Variant

data_fields = Array("Units", "Cost", "Mileage", "Whatever")

For i = 0 To UBound(data_fields)
    Set pf = PvtTbl.PivotFields(data_fields(i))
    pf.Orientation = xlDataField
    ' ... etc.
Next
```

You could even go nuts and build the entire pivot table from an array structure.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pt_layout As Variant

' Tuple format:
' Field name, Orientation, Position, Function, Number format
' (Function and Number format are only used by data fields.)
pt_layout = Array( _
    Array("Client",     xlRowField,    1, Empty,     Empty), _
    Array("Year/Month", xlColumnField, 1, Empty,     Empty), _
    Array("Units",      xlDataField,   1, xlSum,     "0"), _
    Array("Cost",       xlDataField,   2, xlAverage, "#,##0"), _
    Array("Whatever",   xlDataField,   3, xlCount,   "General"))

For i = 0 To UBound(pt_layout)
    Set pf = PvtTbl.PivotFields(pt_layout(i)(0))
    pf.Orientation = pt_layout(i)(1)
    pf.Position = pt_layout(i)(2)

    If pf.Orientation = xlDataField Then
        pf.Function = pt_layout(i)(3)
        pf.NumberFormat = pt_layout(i)(4)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Great info! Thank you. I'll bookmark this thread to study this stuff later.